# jQuery vertical dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works great and does exactly as it should, but there has to be a better way of doing this and I just can't figure out how!

I'm pretty new to jQuery and am trying to use it more myself instead of using plugins and I can get stuff to work fine. It just isn't the tidiest or neatest code, which I'm trying to move away from!

I've included a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9qbmf/) just so you can see the functionality as it currently stands.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Example 1</li>
    <li class="open">Example 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Example 2.1</li>
            <li>Sub Example 2.2</li>
            <li>Sub Example 2.3</li>
            <li>Sub Example 2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="open2">Example 3
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Example 3.1</li>
            <li>Sub Example 3.2</li>
            <li>Sub Example 3.3</li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var menu = $('li.open ul');
menu.css('display','none');
     $('li.open')
     .mouseenter(function(){
          menu.slideDown(400);
     })
     .mouseleave(function(){
          menu.slideUp(400);
     });

var menu2 = $('li.open2 ul');
menu2.css('display', 'none');
    $('li.open2')
    .mouseenter(function(){
         menu2.slideDown(400);
     })
     .mouseleave(function(){
         menu2.slideUp(400);
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting `.open` and `.open2`, you could change your selector to see if there is a child `<ul>`.

```
$('li:has(ul)').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideDown(400);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideUp(400);
})
```

**Edit:** you can also hide all the child `<ul>` nodes at once instead of individually.

```
$('li ul').hide();
```

### Reference

Here are the three main features of jQuery that I used. Each link uses <[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com)> which is a great place to learn about various jQuery functions.

- [:has() selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
- [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mouseenter/mouseleave, you can use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). It combines both events.

`.css('display','none');` can be done with `.hide();`